# Attribute in OrderEntryModel coming as null even though I have defined a default value as 0.0 in items.xml

Tags: shopping-cart, sap-commerce-cloud

We are using hybris 6.7 version.
I have created a new attribute in AbstractOrderEntryModel and I have defined a default value for it in the items.xml as 0.00D since it is a double type.

Now when I login to the storefront and add items to cart, it is working as expected. But when I login to a user who already has an active cart to him, it throws nullpointer. I did not handle the null pointer since I have declared its default value as 0.0 and it can't be null.

Now for resolving this, is it better to handle the null pointer or to create a groovy script to update all the old and existing carts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to update old records. You can update old records with impex, groovy or db query.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would update the existing records that have `null` values for the new attribute.

Handling the exception is also a possible approach, but it's slightly ugly, since you already know it's not supposed to be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

As per good practice, we should update already existing AbstractOrderEntryModel by creating a simple data migration script via groovy, Impex, or DB query.
                 it's not recommended to use a null check at the code level because newly created entries will go to the model life cycle and initdefault interceptor will do the job as you have already defined the default values.